# Checking the exit status of subprocesses on Windows

Tags: c, windows, subprocess, glib

In [gEDA](http://gpleda.org/), we have a helper program that needs to create a subprocess and check its exit status to ensure that it completed successfully.  On Linux, we use something similar to:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static gboolean
build_and_run_command (const gchar *format, ...)
{
  int result, status;
  gchar *args, *standard_error;
  GError *error = NULL;

  /* Set up argument variables */

  if (g_spawn_sync (".",
                    args,
                    NULL,
                    G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH | G_SPAWN_STDOUT_TO_DEV_NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &standard_error,
                    &status,
                    &error)) {
    result = (WIFEXITED (status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0);
  }

  /* Clean up */

  return result;
}
```

The [full source code for the program](http://git.gpleda.org/?p=gaf.git;a=blob;f=utils/src/gsch2pcb.c;h=74e09f0f5c25e4752eed9395fa490d97a258aaf3;hb=HEAD) can be found in our git repository.

Unfortunately, when compiling for Windows using MinGW, we have discovered that `sys/wait.h` doesn't exist, and neither do the `WIFEXITED` or `WEXITSTATUS` macros.  What is the "right way" to check for a normal exit and to retrieve the exit status on Windows using `g_spawn_sync`?  Google has been surprisingly unhelpful!

Comment: Dunno why you expected linux system header to work on widows in the first place...

Comment: I expect nothing to work on Windows at all, and I'm rarely disappointed.  The above code works on everything othr than Windows; I was hoping someone could suggest how to modify it to support that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`g_spawn_async_with_pipes()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes) explains how to do it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows API you normally create processes using CreateProcess. To get the error code (or "success code" ^^) take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ideally, I want to use the GLib functions for working with subprocesses, so that the minimal possible non-portable code needs to be written.